# Proving a limit for factorials

Tags: factorial, gamma-function

On a site generalizing the factorial function, it states, "The probability of repetition gets negligible; we find that the ratio between x!/(x−r)! and x^r approaches 1 as x grows large while r is held fixed." I was wondering how to formally prove this result.

Source: https://www.3blue1brown.com/sridhars-corner/2018/4/21/the-generalized-factorial

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x!/(x-r)!}{x^r} &= \lim_{x \to \infty} \left[\frac{x}{x} \cdot \frac{x-1}{x} \cdot \frac{x-2}{x} \cdots \frac{x-r+1}{x}\right]\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{x} \cdot \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x-1}{x} \cdot \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x-2}{x} \cdots \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x-r+1}{x}
\end{align}$$

Comment: won't the number of terms in the numerator exceed the number of terms in the denominator for fixed r, as x approaches infinity?

Comment: @mathExplorer I think there will be $r$ terms in each, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: yes sorry my mistake there would be x - (x-r) terms which is r terms.

Comment: since the highest power in the numerator is x^r could you just write that since x^r/x^r = 1 as x approaches infinity?

Comment: @mathExplorer Sure, that works too.